# How to save a datetime (date) in NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsuserdefaults

Or there other ways than storing a date as string?

```
// read date
string dateString = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey ("MY_DATE");
myDate = new DateTime ();
myDate = DateTime.ParseExact (dateString, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);

// write date
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString (myDate.Value.ToString ("dd.MM.yyyy"), "MY_DATE");
```

Comment: Why you storing date as a string? Store dates as a date and store strings as string. And what is your problem here?

Comment: @SonerGönül: In Objective-C you take a `NSDate` and use the `setObject` method. In Xamarin iOS I didn't found a `setObject` equivalent. How should I store the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// key
NSString k = new NSString ("key");

// store a date
NSDate val = DateTime.SpecifyKind (DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc);
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey (val, k);

// retrieve a date
NSDate nsdate = (NSDate) NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ValueForKey (k);
DateTime date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(nsdate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Comment: Converting from DateTime to NSDate now requires an explicit conversion